# How to dynamically reference another sheet within a cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a cell named `Income` whose value is referencing a cell in another sheet named `7.17`.  I'm currently hard coding the reference.  So, the value of `Income` is `='7.17'!B38`, where `B38` is the cell that contains the value of `Income` located in the sheet named `7.17`.

I want to pass in a dynamic date reference instead.  So, I can use `=month(today())` in one cell to extract the current month, which returns an integer value, like `7` for July.  I then want to use this as the reference value.  In other words, instead of using `='7.17'!B38`, I want to use something like `=month(today()).17!B38`.

`=month(today())` can be in one cell, say `A1`, and its value (like `7`) can be in a different cell, say `A2`.  Then, I would do something like `=A2.17!B38`

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the INDIRECT function. Your 1st example could be expressed in this case as

```
=indirect(month(today()) & ".17!B38")
```